# input type="file" default language is system language?

Tags: html, browsers, language, operating-system

I have a question, let's say I have `<input type="file" name="image" />`. Will the text of the button will change if user will have different language as his system default one? If so than how can I force this button to use English by default?

Comment: I see no legitimate reason why the components of a webpage should show the OS language instead of the browser language. Just the principle of picking language preference from two different places makes me mad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to change this is by replacing the button, (e.g. with [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)) but I don't see why you would want to.

You shouldn't change the user's system language. They've chosen their system language for a reason, and there's an expectation that their UI will be rendered in this language that they can read/understand.

Comment: +1 Though there are legitimate reasons to enforce UI consistency if the user has control over the web application's language - take the case of someone traveling overseas on an internet cafe computer who has a strong preference for his or her native language.

Comment: @danlefree Heh, tell that FB, who used (may still do) to serve me ads in Spanish when browsing the English version of their site, with English browser settings on a Spanish line...

Comment: I think @danlefree is totally right. If the user explicitely states in which language he wants to use the webapplication, then there should be a way to force a local onto the upload file button, which is independent of the system langauge. Sadly there does not seem to be a solution.